# INSERT data from one table INTO another with the copies (as many as `quantity` field in first table says)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an MySQL table `creatures`:

```
id | name   | base_hp | quantity
--------------------------------
1  | goblin | 5       | 2
2  | elf    | 10      | 1
```

And I want to create `creature_instances` based on it:

```
id | name    | actual_hp
------------------------
1  | goblin  | 5
2  | goblin  | 5
3  | elf     | 10
```

The `id`s of `creatures_instances` are not important and not relevant to `creatures.id`s.

**How can I make it with just the MySQL in the most optimal (in terms of execution time) way?** The single query would be best, but procedure is ok too. I use **InnoDB**.

I know that with a help of e.g. **php** I could:

1. select each row separately,
2. make `for($i=0; $i<line->quantity; $i++)` loop in which I insert one row to `creatures_instances` for each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is to do everything in SQL.  It helps if you have a `numbers` table.  Without one, you can generate the numbers in a subquery.  The following works up to 4 copies:

```
insert into creatures_instances(id, name, actual_hp)
    select id, name, base_hp
    from creatures c join
         (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
         ) n
         on n.n <= c.quantity;
```

Comment: That's a clever one! :) And even without a need of procedure :) I know that I will have no more then `quantity=5` so your code is easy to apply. Thank you, sir.